How can you tell ubuntu to update the time automatically when it connects to the internet, despite the time produced certificate errors?

Running Ubuntu 24.04
Laptop Battery Does Not Work
Every bootup resets time to either last known time, or time default from bios.
There is no dual boot.
Internet will not work until I set the time manually.
"Automatic Date & Time" does not seem to work when I set it. It says it requires the internet, but ...

If I can't browse the web because the date and time is off, does this not also prevent the "Automatic Date & Time" from fetching the proper time?
Edit:
anon@anon-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-1st:~$ timedatectl status
               Local time: Fri 2024-06-07 01:16:27 PDT
           Universal time: Fri 2024-06-07 08:16:27 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2001-01-01 00:24:36
                Time zone: America/Vancouver (PDT, -0700)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no


anon@anon-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-1st:~$ timedatectl timesync-status
       Server: 2620:2d:4000:1::3f (ntp.ubuntu.com)
Poll interval: 34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
 Packet count: 0


Edit:
anon@anon-ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-1st:~$ ping -c2 ntp.ubuntu.com
PING ntp.ubuntu.com (185.125.190.57) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.128.128.128 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 10.128.128.128 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered

--- ntp.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1003ms


Add the output of the commands timedatectl status and timedatectl timesync-statusto your question. Format it as code.  "Automatic Date & Time" uses "network time protocol" or NTP, which is different from the protocols used by the browsers, https. So NTP may still work if HTTP(s) does not work but you have internet connection. I don't know.

@user68186 done.

Are these outputs before you set the time manually, or after? If before, try the command ping -c2 ntp.ubuntu.com and see if you get 0% packet loss or 100% packet loss. if you get 100% packet loss, try ping -c2 185.125.190.57. It pinging the IP address works let me know.

@user68186  It was after I set the time manually, and I only set the time to the day, as I knew the internet would work as long as the date was close enough. I edited the question to output the ping command. I tried the ping commands on two laptops with the wrong time, on two different internet connections. They both gave 100% packet loss.

Does the ping command work if you enter the IP address, instead of the URL?
